# Finding significant images in a set of surveillance camera images

Tags: webcam, vision, surveillance

I've had theft problems outside my house so I setup a simple webcam to capture every second with Dorgem (http://dorgem.sf.net).

Dorgem does offer a feature to use motion detection to only capture frames where something is moving on the screen. The problem is that the motion detection algorithm it uses is extremely sensitive. It goes off because of variations in color between successive shots on my cheap webcam, and it also goes off because the trees in front of the house are blowing in the wind. Additionally, the front of my house is a high traffic area so there is also a large number of legitimately captured frames.

I average capturing 2800/3600 frames every second using Dorgem's motion detection. This is too much for me to search through to find out where the interesting activity is.

I wish I could re-position the camera to a more optimal position where it would only capture the areas I'm interested in, so that motion detection would be simpler, however this is not an option for me.

I think that because my camera has a fixed position and each picture frames the same area in front of my house, then I should be able to scan the images and figure out which ones have motion in some interesting region of that image, throwing out all other frames.

For example: if there's a change in pixel 320,240 then someone has stepped in front of my house and I want to see that frame, but if there's a change in pixel 1,1 then its just the trees blowing in the wind and the frame can be discarded.

I've looked at pdiff, a tool for finding diffs in sets of pictures, but it seems to be also focused on diffing the entire picture, rather than a specific region of it:
http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/

I've also looked at phash, a tool for calculating a hash based on human perception of an image, but it seems too complex:
http://www.phash.org/

I suppose I could implement it in a shell script using imagemagick's mogrify -crop to cherry pick the regions of the image I'm interested in, then running pdiff to find the interesting ones, and using that to pick out the interesting frames.

Any thoughts? ideas? existing tools?

Comment: Surveillance video is mostly used *after* the fact. Useful change detection is not a trivial problem.

Answer (score 0):

cropping and then using pdiff seems like the best choice to me.